# How to override class constants and methods from a module?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a module to define some methods and constants for some classes.

This means the same method or constant can be defined in both the module and the class that includes the module.

In that scenario, I want to have control (preferably in the module definition, or maybe from the caller, without changing the class code) over which one takes precedence.

Often, I want the method or constant defined in the module to be used.

However, it looks like those defined in the class always get used unless I delete them from the class.

```
module A
  def self.included(clazz)
    const_set(:CONST, clazz.name == "B" ? "constant from module A for B" : "constant from module A for C")

    define_method(:a) do
      "from module A"
    end
  end
end

class B
  include A
  CONST = "constant from class B"
  def a
    "from class B"
  end
end

class C < B
  include A
  CONST = "constant from class C"
  def a
    "from class C"
  end
end

b = B.new
c = C.new

p b.a, c.a
p B::CONST, C::CONST
```

Running this on [this REPL](https://replit.com/@EricNa1/FriendlyFumblingOctagons#main.rb) prints

```
main.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant A::CONST
main.rb:3: warning: previous definition of CONST was here
"from class B"
"from class C"
"constant from class B"
"constant from class C"
```

Is there a way I can make this output

```
"from class A"
"from class A"
"constant from module A for B"
"constant from module A for C"
```

without deleting constant `CONST` or method `a` from class B or C?

Answer (score 2):

First, Ruby interpret code line by line from top to bottom, so in your case, Ruby read `module A` before the line define `CONST =`, as a result, the `CONST` defined in class B or C will always the output.

-> move `include A` below `CONST=`

Second, inside `def self.included(clazz)` the self is the `module A` not the class B or C, as a result, the `const_set` method be called by the `module A` itself so there's no `B::CONST` or `C::CONST` is defined here.

-> use `clazz.const_set` inside `def self.included(clazz)`

try this

```rb
module A
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :remove_const, :CONST if base.const_defined?(:CONST)
    base.const_set(:CONST, base.name == "B" ? "constant from module A for B" : "constant from module A for C")
  end
end

class B
  CONST = "constant from class B"
  include A
end
```